# Sharepoint 2013 and managed Paths

Tags: 2013, site-collection

I am new to SharePoint and accidently deleted the managed path to my site collection (and in the process of trying to fix I think I might have changed a few more things as now when I create a new site collection I get the 500 internet error) I was wondering is there a way to restore/recreate a managed pathway or is the best bet just to reinstall?

Comment: What happens when you try to create a managed path with the same name that you deleted?

Comment: I can recreate the path but that doesn't seem to allow me to access the old site collection.

Is there a way to find out what the proper path is (in case I am creating incorrect ones)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the site collection from Central Administration -> Application Management -> View all site collections. And try creating the managed path after that link.

Comment: Well I ended up just restoring it from a backup. However if this happens again I will give this a go. Thanks.